# Sort files into folders, depending on filetype

Tags: shell-script, files, file-types

I have about 2.8TB (yes, terabytes) of data I have recovered, this will be scanned for duplicates, the machine these files reside on is quite old and only has 2GB of memory (works fine for LVM, however), so doing the duplicate scan on it is asking for pain.

My question is this, how can I get Debian to move files into a folder with that filetype, rename automatically where needed without needing to specify a list of filetypes.

I have around 800GB of space free on it, so I can do some testing before letting this run loose on my data.

Comment: What are you meaning by "filetype".  Do you mean "extension" (eg `.txt`)?  Or do you mean the results of the `file` command?  Or...?

Comment: Yes, as in *.jpg, *.mp3 and so on.

Comment: If you're sure that your duplicates are **exactly the same file** then you should compute checksums (e.g. `sha1sum`) and compare those, no need to sort the files into separate directories.

Comment: That's a good idea, except the machine is slow, with low resources.

I have two machines on this task, the slow Debian machine is just the LVM store, files are coming into the machine via an SMB share, the files being pulled off a USB drive, plugged into a fast(er) Windows 10 laptop.

I'd do more in Windows, but getting some programs to see the share as an attached disk for scanning/indexing is a problem, even with it showing as a shortcut or a mapped drive. Getdataback is writing to it via a shortcut in the root of c:

Comment: Another trick you might consider is to look for a python script called "hardlink.py" or something like that. It will search directories for identical files and make them into hard links of each other, saving space.

Answer (score 3):

I wrapped Stephen's code in a script and slightly improved the pipe.

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -e 
set -u 
set -o pipefail

start=$SECONDS

exts=$(ls -dp *.*| grep -v / | sed 's/^.*\.//' | sort -u) # not folders
ignore=""

while getopts ':f::i:h' flag; do
  case "$flag" in
    h)
        echo "This script sorts files from the current dir into folders of the same file type. Specific file types can be specified using -f."
        echo "flags:"
        echo '-f (string file types to sort e.g. -f "pdf csv mp3")'
        echo '-i (string file types to ignore e.g. -i "pdf")'
        exit 1
        ;;
    f)
        exts=$OPTARG;;
    i)
        ignore=$OPTARG;;
    :) 
        echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG" >&2; 
        exit 1;;
    \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
  esac
done

for ext in $exts 
do  
    if [[ " ${ignore} " == *" ${ext} "* ]]; then
        echo "Skiping ${ext}"
        continue
    fi
    echo Processing "$ext"
    mkdir -p "$ext"
    mv -vn *."$ext" "$ext"/
done

duration=$(( SECONDS - start ))
echo "--- Completed in $duration seconds ---"
```

Answer (score 0):

With a directory that looks like

```
$ ls   
another.doc  file.txt  file1.mp3  myfile.txt
```

We can build a list of file extensions with this command:

```
$ exts=$(ls | sed 's/^.*\.//' | sort -u)
```

We can then loop through these extensions moving files into subdirectories:

```
$ for ext in $exts
> do
> echo Processing $ext
> mkdir $ext
> mv -v *.$ext $ext/
> done
```

When this is run we get the following output:

```
Processing doc
'another.doc' -> 'doc/another.doc'
Processing mp3
'file1.mp3' -> 'mp3/file1.mp3'
Processing txt
'file.txt' -> 'txt/file.txt'
'myfile.txt' -> 'txt/myfile.txt'
```

The result:

```
$ ls
doc/  mp3/  txt/

$ ls *
doc:
another.doc

mp3:
file1.mp3

txt:
file.txt  myfile.txt
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming "$ exts=$(ls | sed 's/^.*\.//' | sort -u)" will go through deeply nested folders?

I assume both cp and mv will work, for both testing and the actual move when I'm satisfied this will work? 

I'm also assuming this is .sh (shell) scripting?

(please excuse the incorrect use of tags)

Comment: This only works for a single directory.  You need to be a lot more careful if you have subdirectories because you may have `dir1/file.txt` and `dir2/file.txt` and you don't want them overwriting each other.  You can save this script as `splitdir.sh` in your home directory and then manually call it for each directory (if you have a small number) by `cd`ing into it and running this script.  If you have a lot of directories you can create a second script that goes through each directory and then runs this script once per directory.

Comment: This is needlessly complicated and breaks on file names containing whitespace and other special characters. At least [double quote your variable expansions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)!

Comment: How can I get it to rename files that have the same name? I don't want to babysit this. Getdataback reports there's 955684 folders in this recovery, 4400795 files.

Comment: So you have different files, in different folders, with the same names? And you're ok with having *some* of those files wind up with new names? This just got a lot more complicated, and you probably need to write a proper Python or bash script to do it. Given that your requirements are probably somewhat complicated at this point, I don't think you're going to get anybody here to write it for you. If you want to write your own, and come back if you get stuck, you might get some help.

Comment: I think I have enough in the snippets of script here to deal with what I want to do, but if I get stuck, I'll come back and ask, the copy is still going, it'll probably still be going by the end of this week. If I can't do it under Linux, I'll probably deal with this by moving chucks of data back onto the USB drive, deal with them under Windows and then move them back onto the share, rinse and repeat until done.